# Cmake: how to create a symlink pointing to a installed library file?

Tags: cmake

```
.
├── build
│ └── lib
│  └── foo.so
└── package
 ├── fixed
 │ └── dir
 │  └── structure
 │   └── bar.so
 └── lib
  └── foo.so
```

foo.so is installed from build/lib/ to package/lib/. I want to create a symlink bar.so that's a symlink to “package/lib/foo.so”, and this needs to be done in a different CMakeLists.txt from the one that generate and install the target foo.

Some question:

1. how to ensure the order? The foo.so has to be installed before symlink. I know there's add_dependencies(), but I think it add dependency to the generation of the target, not install?
2. how to create symlink? But I think add_custom_target can help me on this. So the real question is the last one.

Comment: "The foo.so has to be installed before symlink." - Why do you want such constraint? E.g. `ln -s` could create a symbolic link which points to non-existent file.